# What is the -webkit-user-drag css property?

Tags: css, html, drag-and-drop

I've seen this a couple places now, but can't find much information about it:

```
-webkit-user-drag: element
```

Is this part of the standard for HTML5 Drag and Drop? Is this better/worse than using the attribute version:

```
<div draggable="true">my draggable element</div>
```

Edit: I'm familiar with the current spec and using the draggable attribute, what I'm unclear on is exactly the CSS property *-user-drag.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's a Webkit-specific property. Here's what [the WebKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/DragAndDrop.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001233-178644) says about it:

> ### Making an Element Draggable
>
> WebKit provides automatic support to let users drag common items, such as images, links, and selected text. You can extend this support to include specific elements on an HTML page. For example, you could mark a particular div or span tag as draggable.
>
> To mark an arbitrary element as draggable, add the `-webkit-user-drag` attribute to the style definition of the element. Because `-webkit-user-drag` is a cascading style sheet (CSS) attribute, you can include it as part of a style definition, or as an inline style attribute on the element tag. The values for this attribute are listed in Table 4-1.
>
> Values for `-webkit-user-drag` attribute:
>
> - `none`: Do not allow this element to be dragged.
> - `element`: Allow this element to be dragged.
> - `auto`: Use the default logic for determining whether the element should be dragged. (Images, links, and text selections are the only elements that can be dragged.) This is the default value.

It's supported by all browsers using the WebKit rendering engine, so Chrome, newer versions of Opera, Safari, etc. Support in mobile browsers using WebKit may vary depending on the mobile OS.

Comment: Was support discontinued in Chrome 18?

Comment: @nullability: Chrome 33 seems to accept it just fine.

Comment: Edited to emphasize that browsers later than 17 accept it just fine. Confirmed in latest Chrome as of writing.

Answer (score 2):

Brief overview: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Detailed info: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html

Demo: http://html5demos.com/drag

Comment: I was wondering specifically about the -webkit-user-drag css property, which is briefly mentioned in the quirksmode article. I'm thinking it's necessary for older versions of Safari...